# Maven mercurial extension constantly fails

Tags: mercurial, maven, maven-scm

After 2+ hours I was able to get the `maven-scm-provider-hg` extension (for pushing to mercurial repos from Maven) semi working, meaning that it was executing commands instead of just giving errors.

However I think I've run into a wall with this error

```
[INFO] [deploy:deploy {execution: default-deploy}]
[INFO] Retrieving previous build number from pircbotx.googlecode.com
[INFO] Removing C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\LOCALS~1\Temp\wagon-scm1210107000.checkout\pir    cbotx\pircbotx\1.3-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg clone -r tip https://*SNIP*@site.pircbotx.googlecode.com/hg/maven2/snapshots/pircbotx/pircbotx/1.3-SNAPSHOT C:\DOCUME~1\Owner\LOCALS~1\Temp\wagon-scm1210107000.checkout\pircbotx\pircbotx\1.3-SNAPSHOT"
[INFO] EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "hg locate"
[INFO] repository metadata for: 'snapshot pircbotx:pircbotx:1.3-SNAPSHOT' could not be found on repository: pircbotx.googlecode.com, so will be created Uploading: scm:hg:https://site.pircbotx.googlecode.com/hg/maven2/snapshots/pircbotx/pircbotx/1.3-SNAPSHOT/pircbotx-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error deploying artifact: Error listing repository: No such command 'list'.
```

What on earth would cause that error? I'm on a Windows box, so any commands that aren't commands give "'list' is not recognized as an internal or external command...",  not "No such command 'list'."

POM

```
<build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-hg</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </extension>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-scm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-7</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
     ...

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>pircbotx.googlecode.com</id>
        <name>PircBotX Site</name>
        <url>scm:hg:https://site.pircbotx.googlecode.com/hg/maven2/snapshots</url>
        <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

Mercurial version

```
W:\programming\pircbot-hg>hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.7.2)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps you could post the relevant pom snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, not sure if deploying the project artifacts to an SCM is a normal practice.  `maven scm plugin` is usually used for source code related operations like checkout/update/tag, etc.

Secondly, the cause of the error seems to be related to the fact that *maven scm provider for hg* does not support the **list** command as specified in this [scm providers matrix](http://maven.apache.org/scm/matrix.html).  Not sure why and how `mvn deploy` uses this command though.

Comment: Just FYI: I'm using this to deploy a site to a mercurial google code repo since I don't have an actual website yet. I'm just testing with snapshots since their easier. With your answer: I guess I'll try `mvn site` instead and see if it doesn't require the list command

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am raising this as an issue on the `scm-dev` mailing list. Link for anyone interested: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-scm-dev/201101.mbox/%3C166148.61363.qm@web31305.mail.mud.yahoo.com%3E . Lets hope this issue gets resolved